# ERROR: The Compose file docker-compose.yml is invalid

Tags: docker, docker-compose

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  docker-mongo:
   image:
     - mongo:4.2.1
   ports:
     - "27017:27017"
   networks:
     - mynetwork


networks:
  mynetwork:
```

When I execute `docker-compose config` I got the following error:

```
Version in "./docker-compose.yml" is unsupported. You might be seeing this error because you're using the wrong Compose file version. Either specify a supported version (e.g "2.2" or "3.3") and place your service definitions under the `services` key, or omit the `version` key and place your service definitions at the root of the file to use version 1.
For more on the Compose file format versions, see https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/
```

So according to the error message I tried with version `2.2` and `3.3` 
both results in the same error message

```
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.docker-mongo.image contains an invalid type, it should be a string
```

- Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
- Docker version 18.09.6, build 481bc77
- docker-compose version 1.17.1, build unknown

Comment: [Learn yaml in y minutes](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/): `services.docker-mongo.image contains an invalid type which should be a string` where the actual incriminated element holds a list in your file => `image: "mongo:4.2.1"`

Comment: Only for completeness: Docker Compose sets up a single network for your application(s) by default, adding each container for a service to the default network. Containers on a single network can reach and discover every other container on the network. See https://runnable.com/docker/docker-compose-networking

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the error message is self explain, your docker-compose should be like below:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  docker-mongo:
   image: mongo:4.2.1
   ports:
     - "27017:27017"
   networks:
     - mynetwork


networks:
  mynetwork:
```

Comment: why is it specifically 3.7?

Comment: @user2763557 it's just the docker-compose version, not a big deal